# Flutter reverse listview refresh from bottom (after version >= 3)

Tags: flutter, listview, refresh, reverse

After Flutter 3.0 the ListView(reverse: true) in my project has changed behaviour. In older version it can be refreshed from bottom pull but now it doesn't, it can just refresh from top.

I know pull_to_refresh package but I am looking for a core solution like old days.. Github issues indicate that [It is intended](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/104151#issuecomment-1132608029) but I don't wanna reverse flutter version.

Does anybody have idea on flutter 3 and without extra packages?

```
RefreshIndicator(
    key: refreshKey,
    onRefresh: () async { onRefresh(); },
    child: buildMessagesView(messages),
),


  ListView buildMessagesView(List<MessageModel> messages) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      reverse: true,
      itemCount: messages.length,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
        return Message(message: messages.elementAt(index));
      },
    );
  }
```

while ListView reverse:true I expected the Refresh Indicator work by pull from down but it doesn't..

**UPDATE**
Solved. The *ScrollController* answer was very useful for me and I developed a simple widget that wraps the ListView to integrate it into the project. You can find the code here.
https://github.com/bnurd/reversed_listview_refresh

Comment: Actually in flutter 3 ListView behavior is not changed. And It is a bit hard to understand what you meant here. "it can be refreshed from bottom pull". What did you mean here. Swiping from top to bottom? If you clarify what is problem, I think I know how to help you then.

Comment: thank you, what I mean is that I have a message list and when I send a message it should be positioned at the bottom of the page and when a new message arrives I should swipe up from the bottom to refresh. in the old version list view reverse:true wrapped with refresh indicator used to do this automatically. now even if it is reverse it refreshes from the top, not from the bottom. The videos in this link explain what I mean https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/104151#issuecomment-1131500309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the github issue. Actually I realized this behaviour without refresh indicator widget. You can use ScrollController. Create ScrollController instance with listener, attach it to ListView. Write code inside listener that check whether scroll ended. This is listener function sample code:

```
void _onScroll() {
final maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
final currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
if (maxScroll - currentScroll == 0) {'YOUR REFRESH CODE'}
}
```

This is how you attach this listener to ScrollController:

```
  late final _scrollController = ScrollController()..addListener(_onScroll);
```

**IMPORTANT:** Dont' forget to attach scrollController to ListView.

Comment: Thank you, it was a core solution just as I wanted. Updated the question, greetings

Comment: This is not the same behavior at all. Normally you can just swipe to the top without reloading. Then you have to pull a second time. Your solution is executing the code when going to the bottom edge, even if the user just give the scrollbar a huge "push" to the bottom.